# symfony 5.3 Restore a Softdeleteable

Tags: bundle, archive, restore, delete-operator, symfony5

here is my concern:
I use the softdeletable installed with StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle,

I can delete easily, and I have created a recycle garbage can where I can see the deleted items,

However, I can't restore the soft delete items, is there a known method ? I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

Undelete the entity by setting the `deletedAt` field to null

```php
$entity->setDeletedAt(null);
```